# Limiting number of matched digits in regex

Tags: regex

I need to match series of digits between 5 and 7 characters long. I thought this would do the trick:

```
([0-9]{5,7})\w+
```

against this string:

```
Sample text for testing:  22 333 4444 55555 666666 7777777
```

As you can see in the [regexr example](http://www.regexr.com/3a9pb) it does not match digits having 5 numbers, and matches digits longer than 7 numbers long.

Why isn't this working like I expect?

Comment: provide a regex101 link or post your string here.

Comment: Regex is in the example linked in my question.  Here it is again: http://www.regexr.com/3a9pb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does not match digits having 5 numbers, and matches digits longer than 7 numbers long.

Note that the following `\w+` would also match the digits.  `([0-9]{5,7})\w+` expects  5,6,7 digits plus at-least a single word character. But there isn't a word character exist just after to `55555` . So  it fails to match `55555` on your input string.

Comment: Thanks, overlooked the default "w+" in regexr.

Comment: ([\d]{5,7})  - cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `([0-9]{5,7})\w+` doesnt't work as expected, because:

example-string: 12345

```
([0-9]{5,7})\w+
    ^ Matches the digits: 12345

([0-9]{5,7})\w+
             ^ Cannot match a word character (letter, digit, underscore)
```

example-string: 123456789

```
([0-9]{5,7})\w+
    ^ Matches the digits: 1234567

([0-9]{5,7})\w+
             ^ Matches the digits: 89
```

---

To match a number with 5 to 7 digits use:

```
\b\d{5,7}\b

\b ....... matches at the beginning or end of a word.
\d{5,7}... matches a digit in the range of 0-9 between 5 and 7 times.
```